# Intergrating Bing Web Search API with QnA chat bot

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am making a chat bot using the QnA template (Microsoft Azure). Basically, a user asks a question and the bot will try and find the answer in an FAQ document. If it fails, I want it to run a Bing search with the user's query and replies with the most accurate answer. I found this example that uses Bing Web Search API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/nodejs. For now, I just want the bot to reply with the first link of the search for example. 
However, I don't know how to merge the code in the link, with the generated code for the QnA Bot (in Node.js):

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");
var builder_cognitiveservices = require("botbuilder-cognitiveservices");
var request = require('request');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata 
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var tableName = 'botdata';
var azureTableClient = new botbuilder_azure.AzureTableClient(tableName, process.env['AzureWebJobsStorage']);
var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, azureTableClient);

// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.set('storage', tableStorage);

// Recognizer and and Dialog for GA QnAMaker service
var recognizer = new builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
    authKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey || process.env.QnASubscriptionKey, // Backward compatibility with QnAMaker (Preview)
    endpointHostName: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
});

var basicQnAMakerDialog = new builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'Sorry, I cannot find anything on that topic',
    qnaThreshold: 0.3
});

// Override the invokeAnswer function from QnAMakerDialog 
builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog.prototype.invokeAnswer = function (session, recognizeResult, threshold, noMatchMessage) {
    var qnaMakerResult = recognizeResult;
    session.privateConversationData.qnaFeedbackUserQuestion = session.message.text;
    if (qnaMakerResult.score >= threshold && qnaMakerResult.answers.length > 0) {
        if (this.isConfidentAnswer(qnaMakerResult) || this.qnaMakerTools == null) {
            this.respondFromQnAMakerResult(session, qnaMakerResult);
            this.defaultWaitNextMessage(session, qnaMakerResult);
        }
        else {
            this.qnaFeedbackStep(session, qnaMakerResult);
        }
    }
    else {
        this.noMatch(session, noMatchMessage, qnaMakerResult);
    }
};

// API call to Bing
basicQnAMakerDialog.noMatch = function (session, noMatchMessage, qnaMakerResult) {
    var term = session.message.text;
    var key = 'i hid it';

    var options = {
            url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=" + term,
            method: 'GET',
            headers : {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : key
    }
    }; 

    request(options, function(err,res, body){
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
            session.send(noMatchMessage);
        }
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        session.send("I found a thing: " + body["webPages"]["value"][0]["name"]);
    });
};

bot.dialog('basicQnAMakerDialog', basicQnAMakerDialog);

bot.dialog('/', //basicQnAMakerDialog);
        [ 
         function (session, results) {
             session.replaceDialog('basicQnAMakerDialog');
         },

         ]);
```

In the function inside the bot.dialog, I think I should add a condition such as: if the bot returns the default message, open a web page and let the "term" to search be the user's last message. However, I don't know how to code this exactly, and where to do so. Also, I don't know how to exit from the replaceDialog function in order to reply with something other than the default message or the answers in the FAQ.

PS: I don't have much experience with javascript or web development in general. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are implementing involves two steps, extracting out the "noMatch" case to a method so you can make a full response message, and then the API call itself.

**The "noMatch" method.**

First, you will want to override the invokeAnswer function from QnAMakerDialog (This override changes nothing but adding a call to a separate method for the noMatch case.)

```
builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog.prototype.invokeAnswer = function (session, recognizeResult, threshold, noMatchMessage) {
        var qnaMakerResult = recognizeResult;
        session.privateConversationData.qnaFeedbackUserQuestion = session.message.text;
        if (qnaMakerResult.score >= threshold && qnaMakerResult.answers.length > 0) {
            if (this.isConfidentAnswer(qnaMakerResult) || this.qnaMakerTools == null) {
                this.respondFromQnAMakerResult(session, qnaMakerResult);
                this.defaultWaitNextMessage(session, qnaMakerResult);
            }
            else {
                this.qnaFeedbackStep(session, qnaMakerResult);
            }
        }
        else {
                this.noMatch(session, noMatchMessage, qnaMakerResult);
        }
    };
```

After this you will define your basicQnAMakerDialog as usual, but consider making the default message field something for an error case or "no results found". (This doesn't really matter, as you can arbitrarily decide what you send back within the noMatch method, but it's nice to have the default there)

```
var basicQnAMakerDialog = new builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'Sorry, I can't find anything on that topic'
    qnaThreshold: 0.3
});
```

After this you can define the noMatch method seperately.

```
basicQnAMakerDialog.noMatch = function (session, noMatchMessage, qnaMakerResult) {
            session.send(noMatchMessage); //Contains the default message
            this.defaultWaitNextMessage(session, qnaMakerResult);
}
```

Within this method we can call the API or do basically whatever we want.

[Credit to gliddell on this override](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/50)

**The API call.**

Within the noMatch method, we will make an API call to Bing

```
basicQnAMakerDialog.noMatch = function (session, noMatchMessage, qnaMakerResult) {
    var term = session.message.text;
    var key = <Environment Var containing the Bing key>;

    var options = {
        url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=" + term,
        method: 'GET',
        headers : {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : key
        }
    }; 
    request(options, function(err,res, body){
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
            session.send(noMatchMessage);
        }
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        session.send("I found a thing: " + body["webPages"]["value"][0]["name"]);
    });
};
```

You can customize the message you are sending back as much as you like after you get the results from the search.

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful answer! So I changed the default message of basicQnAMakerDialog, copied your invokeAnswer and second noMatch functions (I added the http module and added 'http.' before the request function), and put the Bing key for the key variable. I ran the code and when I input something that's not in the Knowledge Base, with the second noMatch function (with API call to Bing), the bot says nothing afterwards. But with the first noMatch function it answers with the default message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be easier to confirm with some more code, but this version uses the "request" module, not http.

Comment: Okay I forgot to add it. It works now thanks a lot for your help!